# SELECT with mysqli returns null

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to select a row from a table using mysqli but all I can get is a bunch of null values and I don't really know why. The same query works using normal php mysql and if I try to perform the same query on phpMyAdmin using the parameter I pass goes through fine.

Here's the code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass',"db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$coupon = $_GET['coupon'];
$sql = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE coupon=?");
$sql->bind_param('s', $coupon);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
echo $sql;
```

returns

```
"affected_rows":null,
"insert_id":null,
"num_rows":null,
"param_count":null,
"field_count":null,
"errno":null,
"error":null,
"error_list":null,
"sqlstate":null,
"id":null
```

I already tried to search for an answer either here and on google but I couldn't find anything close to my problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does mysqli_error() say? You need to add some error checking.

Comment: Are you sure `mysqli_prepare()` is returning a statement instead of false? Are you ensure `$_GET['coupon']` is returning what you expected?

Comment: For 'evans sake. **R.T.?.M** Try fetching a result. `$sql` is the result of a `prepare` not a result row

Comment: @Mike The `mysqli_error()` is empty.

Comment: @Chris Yes, both the `$_GET['coupon']` and `mysql_prepare()` work fine

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually you're right, my fault. Many thanks

Comment: please post your solution as ANSWER not a question edit and dont mark title with 'solved', just creates mess. thanks\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> author's final solution (moved from question content):

As suggested by user @RiggsFolly I wasn't fetching the results at all, plus I was mixing procedural and OOP approaches as suggested by user @Alex . Here's the working code for future reference to anyone who will arrive here with a similar problem:

```
$coupon = $_GET['coupon'];
if ($sql = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE coupon=?;")){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 's', $coupon);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql, $ID, $coupon, $discount, $uses);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql);
    $data = array(
        'ID' => $ID,
        'coupon' => $coupon,
        'discount' => $discount,
        'uses' => $uses
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must decide if you're using procedural or OOP approach. From your code, it seems you call the procedural version of mysqli extension and afterwards you try using objects. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) examples, both object oriented and procedural and decide on a single one.

Comment: This is not really an answer - more of a comment.